# Curvature of curve defined in terms of unusual function

Tags: differential-geometry

My textbook, Oneill's Elementary Differential Geometry, defines a curve in terms of the function $f$:
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}0, &\text{for } t\leq0\\
e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}, &\text{for } t\gt0\end{cases}$$

The curve is defined $$a(t)={t,f(t),f(-t)}$$
The book states that the curvature is only zero at $t=0$. But when I calculate it, I get that the curvature is proportional to the length of $$a'(t)\times a''(t)$$
I get the first and second components of this product equal to zero. For the third component, for $t\gt0$
I get $$4\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^6}-6\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^4}$$
Setting this equal to zero, I get $$t=\sqrt{2/3}$$
So my result is at variance with the textbook. Have I made an error? If so, where?

Comment: I haven't checked your calculation, but remember that if $t>0$, then $f(-t)=0$, and if $t<0$, then $f(t)=0$.

Comment: Right, so for t>0,

Comment: Right, so for t>0, $\alpha\prime=0,\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^6},0-\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^4},0$

Comment: I meant to say $\alpha^\prime=1,\frac{2e^{-1/t^2}}{t^3},0$ and $\alpha{\prime\prime}=0,4\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^6}-6\frac{e^{-1/t^2}}{t^4},0$

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, you're right. If you graph the curve, you have an inflection point, hence a point with $\kappa=0$. The interesting thing about this curve is not its curvature, but that it has torsion $\tau=0$ everywhere except at $t=0$, and yet it is not planar.